# C++ socket's send() causes system error 10053

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, send

I'm trying to send a message from my client to my server (currently they are both running in the same process, but I don't think it matters).
The connection is established well (I can see it with "CurrPorts" - much more user friendly than TcpView).
But then, when I send the message, I get the error:
"An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine." (number 10053)
and then the connection breaks...

here is the relevant code:

```
bool Client::Send(void* msg, int size)
{
    int sockId = m_socket.GetId();
    struct sockaddr_in remote = m_socket.GetRemotePoint().GetBasePoint();
    const char* buf = (const char*)msg;
    int error = send(sockId, buf, size, 0);
    //int g = GetLastError();
    //if (g != 0)
    //{
    //  g = g;
    //}
    return (error != -1);
}
```

Does anybody know what's going on?
thanks :)

Comment: please post the relevant code snippet.

Comment: the part with the "send" command?

Comment: do you have multiple threads in your program?

Comment: yes, i do. both in the client and in the server.

Comment: well, no clue here. what about the client code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm so stupid... :/
I have this class `MySocket` which I create during `Accept`, but in its destructor, I CLOSE the socekt.
thanks everybody :)

Answer (score 2):

That's `WSAECONNABORTED` which means that your local machine has killed the connection. Possibly a firewall issue?

- http://search.microsoft.com/results.aspx?mkt=en-us&q=10053%20Software%20caused%20connection%20abort